# how to call javascript function when <input> value is already modify by another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The first keyup event will change the value of one input but on the change of one input `gn()` in not calling.

This is my code

```js
function fn() {
  document.getElementById("one").value = "abc"
}

function gn() {
  document.getElementById("two").value = "def"
}
```

```html
<input type="number" onkeyup="fn()">
<input type="number" id="one" onchange="gn()">
<input type="number" id="two">
```

Comment: Setting an element's value (eg `element.value = 'something'`) does NOT trigger a change event. You can manually trigger the change event, or make sure to call any relevant functions after changing the value.

Comment: generally onchange is fired onblur event.. so assigning value by code will not fire the event.. so it has to be invoked from code.. function fn(){ document.getElementById("one").value = "abc"; document.getElementById("one").onchange() }

Comment: Also, why are you trying to set numeric fields to string values? Did I miss a memo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first assignment wasn't working because you were trying to set a "number" input to a non-numeric value.

The second assignment wasn't working because the onchange event isn't triggered when the value of a field is modified by script; you have to create and dispatch the event manually:

```js
function fn() {
  // This will work because the #one input is now type="text"
  document.getElementById("one").value = "abc";

  // now create and dispatch a change event on the field you modified:
  var evt = new Event('change');
  document.getElementById("one").dispatchEvent(evt)
  // (Or, of course, just call gn() directly here.)
}

function gn() {
  document.getElementById("two").value = "def"
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="fn()">
<input type="text" id="one" onchange="gn()">
<input type="text" id="two">
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to set the value of a number input to a string, and not even one that can be cast to a number.

Replace your functions with:

```
document.getElementById("one").value = "123";
```

or

```
 document.getElementById("one").value = 123;
```

and that will work.

If you want the input to be set to abc, you should switch the input type from number to text

```
<input type="text" id="one" onchange="gn()">
```

**EDIT**
I copied my proposed solution of changing inputs into text into an HTML file. Below is the entirety of that file:

```
  1 <html>
  2 
  3 <input type="text" onkeyup="fn()">                                                                                                                                                  
  4 <input type="text" id="one" onchange="gn()">
  5 <input type="text" id="two">
  6 
  7 <script>
  8     function fn(){ document.getElementById("one").value = "abc"}
  9     function gn(){ document.getElementById("two").value = "def"}
 10 </script>
 11 </html>
```

With this, a keyup event in the first box will change the 2nd input to abc. Changing the value (as in, entering in a value and clicking out of) the 2nd box will make the 3rd box have a value of def.

Comment: it is still not working after changing "number" to "text" or "abc" to "123".

Comment: Hmm can you post your full code example after making the change? I just copied it into an HTML file and it worked for me.

Comment: this doesn't work on my range input. The chosen answer does.